# GooglePlayServices banners are not displayed on Nexus 7

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services

We've been experiencing issues, specifically with the nexus 7, across all our apps, where it does not display banners.
The proclaimed banner is 320X50, AdFilled and AdReceived events are triggered and the flow is identical to any other device.
On the other hand AdFailed is never called, after inspecting it in the monitor I can determine that for some reason the ViewSwitcher does not contain the ad's WebView as a child (as opposed to the "normal" behaviour on any other device).
We are working on Xamarin using GooglePlayServices rev 19.0.0.1 and the provider is DFP/MOPUB

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using GooglePlayServices 19.0.0.1? I believe the latest binding is up to 22.0.0.2 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices/) not sure if that will solve your problem, but worth a try.

Comment: @codechinchilla yes, we are aware of this, the rev 19 usage is a constraint for a product we're supporting, however, even on previous versions of GPS this problem occurs on the n7/kindle fire, do you think they fixed the issue?

Comment: I'm not certain - you could try making a separate dummy project and using 22.0.0.2 and see you get the same results? If you do, I'd report it to Xamarin and see if they can give you some support (I'm sure they'd also appreciate the bug report).